# What is "pooled eyed" (or "pulled eyed"/"pooed eyed")?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I heard a strange word in a movie description several times:

> Mitch looks **pooled-eyed**

This describes the character Mitch looks unhappy and frustrated after his phone call was cut short. As additional information, here is an [audio clip](https://clyp.it/jrsppcxk) (via an audio sharing site).

And in another scene:

> Steve: A lot of people showed up after the service, huh?
>
> Walt: Yeah, well, I suppose they heard there's gonna be a lot of ham. I'll go down in the basement and get some chairs.
>
> Steve: Oh I can do that, Dad.
>
> Walt: No, I need them now, not next week.
>
> Narrator: Tubby, 40 something Steve looks **pooled-eyed**.

The word here supposedly means the same as the first scene. Here's an [audio clip](https://clyp.it/jljai23q). I can't find a dictionary that shows any of these words is an adjective meaning "frustrated". Does "pooled-eyed" have this meaning? Or is it another word? What does it mean exactly?

Comment: is it really 'pooled' eye?

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd relate it to tears *pooling* in one's eyes. I'm not 100% sure those are the words used in the clip, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is "put out" not "pooled eyed"

> Mitch looks put out.

The second clip says

> Tubby, forty-something Steve looks put out"

The adjective "put out" means "taking offence" or "indignant", or perhaps "confused". It comes from using a phrasal verb in a passive form. To "[be put out](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/put-out?q=put%20out)" means to be upset.

> Jay was really put out when I told him there were lots of mistakes in his report, but I wasn't trying to be rude, I just wanted to help

Comment: This! I kept looking where "pulled-eyed" could come from (fun fact: it's apparently a racial slur in Portuguese...), but "put out" fits pretty well.